# cannot be inserted record into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add new record but error says "cannot inserted". Below is the code I use (assume i have been declared those variables below).

```
$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE serialno='$serialno'";

//checking if the item is available in db
$check =  $this->db->query($sql6) ;
$count_row = $check->num_rows;

//if the item is not in db then insert to the table
if ($count_row == 0){
    $poster = "Admin";
    $sql6 = "INSERT INTO records SET itemname='$itemname', itemdesc='$itemdesc', brand='$brand', serialno='$serialno', nostock='$nostock', price='$price', onsale='$onsale', $poster='$poster', thedate='date('Y-m-d')'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql6) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted");
    return $result;
}
else { return false;}
```

and my database structure is

```
id (int, autoincrement)itemname (varchar), itemdesc (varchar), brand (varchar), serialno (varchar), nostock (int), price (varchar), onsale (tinytext), poster (tinytext), thedate (date)
```

and i got an error saying "cannot inserted". anyone have ideas or clues whats wrong about my code? any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

PS: I tried to display all the post data e.g. ($itemname, $itemdesc, etc.) by echo $itemname, $itemdesc, etc.. and it did display correctly so it might be there is an issue into my query.

Comment: `thedate='date('Y-m-d')` should be `thedate=NOW()`

Comment: @JohnConde actully `CURDATE()` is far more efficient ;)

Comment: @JohnConde: change the date to thedate=NOW() and still same error

Comment: `echo $sql6; ` paste that in to the question

Comment: @Dagon: what you mean by "echo $sql6; paste that in to the question"?

Comment: Why check first? What happens if someone enters the value while you're checking?

Comment: exactly that, echo the string, put it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO records SET itemname='$itemname', itemdesc='$itemdesc', brand='$brand', serialno='$serialno', nostock='$nostock', price='$price', onsale='$onsale', $poster='$poster', thedate=''
```

Change this layout to :

```
INSERT INTO records (itemname,itemdesc, brand, serialno,nostock, price,onsale,poster, thedate) VALUES ($itemname,$itemdesc ...the values... ".date('Y-m-d').", )
```

This is the process shape:

```
INSERT <tablename> (<columns1>,<columns2>) VALUES ($value1,$value2)
```

This code will insert one line of new data into the table specified, and return true on success.

You also probably need to change your column named `$poster` . This is probably incorrect, the column name shouldn't  be the column value - not a syntax break as such but bad method.

### STEP 2

Still doesn't  work - so get some detailed feedback, and replace

```
die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted");
```

With

```
die($this->db->error." :: Data cannot be inserted");
```

This will give you much more useful feedback from the MySQL object.

Comment: still same error. i tried to display all the post data e.g. ($itemname, $itemdesc, etc.) by echo $itemname, $itemdesc, etc.. and it did display correctly so it might be there is an issue into my query.

Comment: @CodeDemon on the assumption that you changed the insert to the above form, try my step 2 adjustment in my answer

Comment: thank you for the answer. i figured out the problem was in my mysql column name "serialno", the cause of the error is because its unique and int so I remove the unique setting and change the int to varchar.

Comment: Glad you found the anwser, I find often with my own MySQL that the answer to errors is often not where I would expect. Pleased you got it :)